# Object detection in Open CV

Tags: python, opencv

I am using this script for Object Detection using OpenCV

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/18/real-time-object-detection-with-deep-learning-and-opencv/

Issue:

I am trying to customize this only for Person Detection. Can someone help out.

I am trying to compare the detection output with "person", but this does not seem to work out.

Answer (score 0):

First, you would want to ensure that your model has been trained to detect books. Then you can simply ignore all classes(`On line 21`) except the person class by checking only the index and probability associated with the person class. Alternatively you could fine-tune your network to apply detect person. Reference : 
Adrian Rosebrock (Author of your code)